# Quelles sont les expressions françaises pour "**display mode**" et "**inline mode**"?

Tags: typographie, technologie

Lorsque les mathématiciens américains, typographes américains, et compositeurs de caractères americains composent leur travail à l'aide d'un programme informatique, les gens de l'imprimerie parlent de "texte en ligne" (***inline text***) et de "phrase d'affichage" (***display text***).

Les "phrases d'affichage" (***display phrases***) ont des lettres plus grandes que les "phrases en ligne" (***inline phrases***), relativement parlant.

De plus, les "formules d'affichage" sont centrées sur la page.

"formules en ligne" contient des lettres plus petites que les formules d'affichage.

Les "formules en ligne" sont généralement justifiées à gauche sur une page de texte.

"formules en ligne" utilisent le mot "en ligne" car les formules en ligne apparaissent au milieu d'une ligne de texte.

Par exemple, veuillez considérer la ligne de texte suivante

> "l'herbe nord-américaine des porcs nommée d'après Palmer, également connue sous le nom d'amaranthe, est vilipendée et détestée par la plupart des jardiniers américains. L'***herbe des porcs*** est une céréale, comme le blé, sauf que les feuilles de l'herbe des porcs sont plus grandes que les feuilles de blé et les feuilles sont comestibles.

l'expression "***herbe des porcs***" est au format en ligne car "***herbe des porcs***" apparaît au milieu de la ligne de texte.

si un mot ou une phrase est extrait d'une ligne et que le mot ou la phrase est affiché au milieu de la page, les mathématiciens américains utilisent la phrase "mode d'affichage".

Si je devais créer une version française des outils de composition **LaTeX**, qui utilisaient des expressions françaises telles que "lettres en gras pour les tableaux noirs" au lieu de "letters in bold black board", alors quelles sont les expresions françaises pour "texte d'affichage justifié au centre" et "inline texte"?

quelles sont les expressions françaises pour "**display mode**" et "**inline mode**"?

Comment: Au passage, on parle rarement de "mathématiciens" dans ce contexte, mais plutôt d'informaticiens. "Computer science" = "informatique".

Comment: Le sens de "display mode" et "inline mode" est fortement lié au contexte des expressions mathématiques de Latex. Dans un tutoriel Latex en français, on peut voir "mode en ligne" et "hors texte". personnelement, je préfererais "mode imbriqué" (nested mode) et "mode disjoint" (detached mode).

Comment: L'expression "herbe des porcs" n'est pas utilisée en Français. Il s'agit probablement d'amarante réfléchie.  https://www.picturethisai.com/fr/wiki/Amaranthus_retroflexus.html

Answer (score 1):

> Tiré de *Latex, l'essentiel*, Denis Bitouzé et Jean-Côme Charpentier 2010, Pearson

> **Mode en ligne** Ce mode est utilisé au cours d'une phrase par exemple pour indiquer que la fonction *f* définie par *f(x)=x-1*, est affine ».

Le terme « *mode en ligne* » correspond donc à « in line mode ».

> **Mode hors texte** On recourt à ce mode lorsqu'une formule est suffisamment importante, longue ou complexe pour mériter de figurer sur une ou plusieurs lignes à elle toute seule.

Le terme « *mode hors texte* » correspond donc à « display  mode ».

« texte d'affichage justifié au centre » : mode hors texte, centré (Latex \centering, ragged at both ends )